# Unable to see MAUI templates in VS 2022 version 17.7

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

[image]
I have VS 2022 17.7, which is the latest version, however in this installation I am unable to see or use MAUI project templates
[image]
To start using MAUI project templates, Yesterday (12-Aug-2023) I had upgraded from VS 17.2 to VS 17.7, even after this upgrade I wasnt able to see any MAUI project templates in create new project. I uninstalled the entire VS 2022 and did fresh installation of VS 2022 17.7 today as well, still no MAUI templates are visible, How do I get these MAUI templates to start using them ?
[image]

I also tried to install manually in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022, got an error
[image]

After Liqun suggestion, tried the command in windows command prompt as well still the same issue as shown below

[image]

Please help guys, is there any steps I am missing ?

Comment: Have you tried install them manually by running ```dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates```?

Comment: You may also check if all necessary workloads have been installed using [dotnet workload list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-list)  and [dotnet workload install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-install) command can help you installs one or more optional workloads.

Comment: Yes @LiqunShen-MSFT, I tried installing using this command , but got the error which I have given screenshot in the edited question

Comment: Have you tried ```dotnet workload list``` command?

Comment: Could you tell me where I need to execute the command, how to access ? perhaps thats where I am making a mistake

Comment: You could try to type these commands in Command Prompt and see if it works.

Comment: I executed these commands in **Windows Command Prompt** and hadn't seen the error.

Comment: Can these commands be executed now?

Comment: Let me try that and would update you soon , thanks

Comment: I opened just the Windows Command Prompt and tried to run dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates, but still the same issue as shown in the last image in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some similar issues on GitHub and StackOverflow. I thought they may be helpful.

[WINDOWS X64 CANT FIND .NET 5.0.10](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962)
. In this  thread, [mairaw comments](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962#issuecomment-780084535) said that it might because you have installed both versions 32-bit and 64-bit, and so the 32-bit was the first one added to the system's path. You may try his solution.

Another similar thread: [No .NET SDKs were found](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8327)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes this was the case, I removed VS2019 that was installed in my laptop, which I dont have any use anymore. and now it is working fine. Thank you Liqun Shen